# Server side equivalent of Window.Location.getParameter() in GWT

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

On the client side I am able to retrieve URL parameters in GWT by

```
String parameterName = Window.Location.getParameter("parameterName");
```

Doing the same server side however gives me this exeption:

```
[...]
threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.google.gwt.user.client.Window$Location.getQueryString(Window.java:262)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.Window$Location.ensureParameterMap(Window.java:321)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.Window$Location.getParameter(Window.java:211)
at com.icada.idea.server.CurrentUser.getUser(CurrentUser.java:31)
```

Where line 31 in CurrentUser reads:

```
String noLogin= Window.Location.getParameter("nologin");
```

So how do I get the URL parameter server side? Or is it the only way to pass as a parameter to the method I am calling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server side, you don't have a Window. All you get from the client is a request - and that request may contain parameters (GET parameters or POST parameters).

You can retrieve them by using

```
request.getParameter("parameterName");
```

The request is available in Servlets, e.g. in the `doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)` and `doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)` methods.

If you're using GWTRPC, you could use `getThreadLocalRequest()`, but as you usually don't post the Window's parameters as POST parameters with a GWTRPC call, it would be more natural to pass the parameters you require as method parameters.

Comment: Your're right, the parameter is not sent with the GWTRPC so I'll have to send it as a method parameter.